# HTML video resize to always fit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, video

I am looking for simple solution to always keep aspect ratio of a video but also to always fit the video inside the browser window for both the width and the height.

So far all the solutions I have found have been fitting only by width, but I need also to fit height. :}

Comment: Hey Štěpán, Do you have any code samples you can provide?

Comment: try `display:flex` or `display:run-in`

Comment: HI! So far I am using this solution (https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php) which works for width but doesn't care about height of a viewport.

Comment: What you are asking for, the best I can tell, contradicts itself.  You want the video to maintain aspect ratio, yet adjust its height and width base on the screen.

Comment: No, i don't want it to adjust it's width, i just want to keep aspect ratio and also fit the viewport. Diagonally resize to say that exactly. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote this for images originally for another question on SO, but it should work for just about any element. Just change the first variable to match your video element. You can also drop the for loop if you are only resizing a single element.

JS:

```
function resize() {
    var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img'); 

    var w = window.innerWidth;
    var h = window.innerHeight;
    //console.log(w);
    //console.log(h);

    for (i = 0; i < img.length; i++) { 
        var ratio = (img[i].clientHeight / img[i].clientWidth);
        if (img[i].clientHeight > h && img[i].clientWidth < w) {
            img[i].style.height = h + "px";
            img[i].style.width = (h / ratio) + "px";
        }
        if (img[i].clientHeight <= h && img[i].clientWidth < w && ratio > 1) {
            img[i].style.height = h + "px";
            img[i].style.width = (h / ratio) + "px";
        }
        if (img[i].clientWidth >= w) {
            img[i].style.width = w + "px";
        }
        if (img[i].clientHeight < h && img[i].clientWidth <= w  && ratio < 1) {
            img[i].style.width = w + "px";
        }
    }
}

resize();
window.onresize = resize;
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hopkins_matt/k7t26sw5/

Comment: Thanks Matt, I have edited this little bit myself and solve the problem! Never did Javascript before, was a nice challenge. :)

Comment: Awesome! Glad to help.

Answer (score 3):

[Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#responsive-embed) does this. The trick is that CSS padding bottom is computed based on the width of the element.

```
.video-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* calculate by aspect ratio (h / w * 100%) */
}
.video-container .video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

<div class="video-container">
  <video class="video"></video>
</div>
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/ozxgk7fL/). It works with `<embed>`, `<object>`, `<iframe>`, and `<video>` tags. My example is just a colored `<div>` that keeps its' aspect ratio constant.

Answer (score 1):

Try with Javascript...

```
function updateHeight()
{
    var videoHeight = 9 * videoDom.offsetWidth / 16;
    videoDom.style.height = vidoeHeight + "px";
}

window.onload = function()
{
  updateHeight();
}

window.onresize = function()
{
  updateHeight();
}
```

Assuming your video has 16:9 aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the CSS only route. YouTube had the solution I was looking for which was keeping width, and height in a 16:9 ratio.

```
video {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 480px;
    height: calc((9 / 16) * 100vw);
    max-height: calc(100vh - 169px);
}
```

With HTML5, the aspect of the video will mold to the parent no matter the video's ratio.